# is there a way to deal with an error followed after using function "Folder.Files" ? and what's the nature of origin of this error

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

The problem is - I'm getting this gigantic error with 60 rows after i tried to retrieve data from the folder which is on our corporate network disc. THe thing is my Excel file (which i created the connection from) is on my desktop.

After that i ask one of colleagues to do exactly the same - it all went just fine without any errors. So i'm wondering what's wrong with what i'm doing:

1. I create en Excel file on my desktop
2. Inside this file create an empty query (go to Data - Get data - other sources - empty query)
3. In this query do a simple function

```
=Folder.Files("Here i put the folder which i want to get data from")
```

4. press enter
5. get this one [the screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcvnT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to your foler and files structure, it's nearly impossible to help debug this one for you.

If you're having issues with the [`Folder.Files()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-files) function, then maybe you can try using the [`Folder.Contents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-contents) function to see if that can help resolve the issue?

Alternatively, try loading the files to SharePoint, and using the [`SharePointFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharepoint-files) or [`SharePoint.Contents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharepoint-contents) functions instead? They may be a little more robust for you, instead of using your local folder directories.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a SharePoint Server here at work. Also the "Folder.Contents()" function triggers the same error. Instead of writing the whole path in the argument, i decided to point disc "S:\" only. The result is the same again. What can be wrong with this ?